# Continuous BSOD with 'System Service Exception' with HP G4 440 running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Every ten minutes or so my Windows keeps blue screening on me with the error "System Service Exception". This small window doesn't allow me to even install updates(which i think might be the issue,since there are several updates pending). I have tried entering into safe mode with networking but for some reason when i enter that mode it says "Networking cannot be used in safe mode", even after explicitly choosing the 5th option in the startup menu. I can't for the life of me find someone else facing this exact problem and id really appreciate any help. I'm running Windows 10 on a HP Probook g4, if it's of any use.

Comment: Have you tried repairing Windows?

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode and see if it still freezes every 10 minutes?

Comment: @DavidPostill Repairing windows would mean that i lose all my programs installed, and i cannot afford that right now , so im still looking for a less destructive solution.

Comment: @LPChip It's alright in safe mode

Comment: @need_to_know_now There are repair options that keep existing programs ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah so the methods i tried are System restore(failed) and Startup Repair(which just went on for hours so i had to force shutdown). Do you know any other methods?

Comment: Then I suggest to boot into safe mode with networking capabilities, and perform your updates there. ;)

Comment: @LPChip Please read my question description once again to understand why i cannot do what you're asking of me

Answer (score 0):

Update BIOS and then ALL remaining drivers. Use the HP Driver update application to do this.

Then run a Windows 10 Repair Install using the Media Creation Link. Run the second choice in the screen, run in place, try first the option to Keep Everything.  There may be a couple of restarts along the way. Certainly do a final restart and test.

You might also use the HP hardware support application to check all hardware.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Note: If all the above fails to work, then it is most likely (over 90%) that you will need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: The Media Creation Link requires me to run it through windows. Like i stated in my question, it keeps crashing every 10 minutes or so. And neither is safe mode with networking working either, so im at a loss here :(

Comment: Try first updating Drivers - each driver can be upgraded in that time.  Then run the hardware test tool as it may finish as well.  Try both before trying the repair install

Comment: You mean update the drivers by going through device manager and individually checking each device?

Comment: I would certainly try that to see if the machine can be made to work.

Comment: I was following the steps on [this page](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/windows-10-reboot-loop.html) and ended up deleting my profile registry keys. This has ended up not allowing me to log into windows even after trying to change my password multiple times. So then I followed [this](https://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/30720-cant-log-my-account-after-deleting-registry-files.html) to repair that issue, but to no avail. Now whenever i select Windows 10 from grub, it goes into Startup Repair which inevitably fails and then I get stuck on a purple dashed  screen.

Comment: When the above happens (continuous startup repairs) with no result, you need to reinstall Windows.  I have seen this numerous times.

Comment: Yeah i think im going to need to do that. When they say it won't delete any of my data but will delete my programs installed, what "data" are they talking about keeping back?

Comment: When you do a full Windows install, you need to back up all your data and then after installation, reinstall your programs and recover your data.

Comment: How do i Backup windows when i can't even get to the login screen?

Comment: Try starting with a USB key to recover your data. You cannot backup Windows in this state.  Just recover your data.

Comment: I have Ubuntu dual booted on this laptop. So i guess ill just take a backup of whatever i can through Ubuntu and then reinstall Windows.

Comment: I adjusted my answer above to include the need to reinstall

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. So i tried to reinstall windows but i get the error "The selected disk has an MBR partition table..." and ive seen the solutions online, the only way to do it is to convert my drive into a GPT-style partition. But that would mean reformatting my entire hard drive which i cannot afford to do because i have Ubuntu dual booted too. Could you suggest an alternative? I read something about booting into EFI mode but im just not being able to do it, so any help there would also be greatly appreciated. Cheers man!